# Event default not triggering in jQuery module

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm attempting to write a jQuery script to store an authentication token from a REST API service. I had a block of working code but decided to modularize to make the application more scalable. Now, it seems that the preventDefault portion is no longer working.

```
            <form action="/" id="authorize">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label><br />
                    <input type="text" id="username" required /><br />
                    <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
                    <input type="password" id="password" required /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Authorize" /><span id="isValid" class="checkContainer">&nbsp;</span>
            </form><hr />
            <label for="serviceType" class="fieldDisabled">Method: </label>
            <select id="serviceType" disabled>
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
```

The script is saved separately as authorize.js and invoked in the module as follows:

```
            <script src="js/authorize.js"></script>
            <script>                        
                    $(document).ready(function() {                  
                            Authorize.init();
                    });
            </script>
```

Here's the module itself:

```
            var s;
            var Authorize = {
                    token: null,
                    settings: {
                            username: $("#username"),
                            password: $("#password"),
                            form: $("#authorize"),
                            validationIcon: $("#isValid"),
                            selector: $("#serviceType"),
                            selectorLabel: $("label[for='serviceType']"),
                            serviceSelector: $(".methodFieldDisabled"),
                            url: "redacted"
                    },
                    init: function() {
                            s = Authorize.settings;
                            this.bindUIActions();
                    },
                    bindUIActions: function() {
                            s.form.submit(function(event) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    data = Authorize.buildJSON(s.username.val(), s.password.val());
                                    Authorize.getToken(json);
                            });
                    },
                    buildJSON: function(username, password) {
                            var data = {};
                            data['grant_type'] = password;
                            data['username'] = username;
                            data['password'] = password;
                            return data;
                    },
                    getToken: function(data) {
                            $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: s.url,
                                    data: data,
                                    success: function(json) {
                                        Authorize.success(json);
                                    },
                                    error: function(json) {
                                        Authorize.error(json);
                                    }
                            });
                    },
                    success: function(json) {
                            Authorize.token = json.accessToken;
                            Authorize.revealServiceSelector();
                    },
                    error: function(json) {
                            Authorize.hideServiceSelector();
                    },
                    revealServiceSelector: function() {
                            s.serviceSelector.hide();
                            if(s.validationIcon.hasClass("invalid")) {
                                    s.validationIcon.removeClass("invalid");
                            }
                            selectorLabel.removeClass("fieldDisabled");
                            selector.prop("disabled", false);
                            s.validationIcon.addClass("valid");
                    },
                    hideServiceSelector: function() {
                            s.serviceSelector.hide();
                            if(s.validationIcon.hasClass("valid")) {
                                    s.validationIcon.removeClass("valid");
                            }
                            selectorLabel.addClass("fieldDisabled");
                            selector.prop("disabled", "disabled");
                            s.validationIcon.addClass("invalid");
                    }
            };
```

I've been toiling over this for about a day now and can't seem to locate the point of failure. When the form is submitted, it redirects to the root directory of the server instead of executing the script as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few typos which stopped the code in its tracks. The submission was the default behavior as your code failed to complete.

Use a debugger to see the errors at runtime (get to know and love your F12 debugging tools in Chrome etc!):

1) You have the wrong variable (json instead of data) on the line below so you get an error:

```
bindUIActions: function () {
    s.form.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        data = Authorize.buildJSON(s.username.val(), s.password.val());
        Authorize.getToken(data);            // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    });
```

2) You also failed to put your scope (s) on a couple of variables:

```
revealServiceSelector: function () {
    s.serviceSelector.hide();
    if (s.validationIcon.hasClass("invalid")) {
        s.validationIcon.removeClass("invalid");
    }
    s.selectorLabel.removeClass("fieldDisabled");
    s.selector.prop("disabled", false);
    s.validationIcon.addClass("valid");
},
hideServiceSelector: function () {
    s.serviceSelector.hide();
    if (s.validationIcon.hasClass("valid")) {
        s.validationIcon.removeClass("valid");
    }
    s.selectorLabel.addClass("fieldDisabled");
    s.selector.prop("disabled", "disabled");
    s.validationIcon.addClass("invalid");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your from action is pointed to "\" which is the root of your directory. Instead point it to the file that contains the code you want to fire.

Comment: If you check the code, you will see that it is supposed to hijack the `submit` event. That "\" should never be used (it directs to "reacted" instead) :)

Comment: And the actual problem is that the code has runtime errors and did not actually get to `evt.preventDefault()`, hence the form still submitting :)